# The Millionaire dies and his family and relatives gather

Tags: humor

Multi millionaire Frankenhouser dies. His family and a bunch of relatives gather at his Lawyer's office eager to learn about his will.

It was a simple Video Message from him

"Most of my money goes to various charities. But I have left 10 Million Dollars in a password protected safe. You will get just one chance to open the safe. My lawyer will make sure of that. But you greedy morons have to figure out the password. I will make it easy for you. It is 12345678. Now go for it".

[image]

All his relatives tried. They started with 12345678 which obviously did not work. Tried all word versions like onetwothreefourfivesixseveneight with lower and upper case combinations. No dice. Also tried the word/number combinations like 1two3four etc

So what was it?

Note: This a humor tagged puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is it's

> 2444666668888888

Because

> one 2, three 4s, five 6s and seven 8s